# Control a servo with arduino

Tags: c#, arduino

I'm trying to control a servo with arduino uno and C# but the servo doesn't move

Here is the Arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servoT1;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
   servoT1.attach(9); 
}
int i=0;
void loop()
{
   if (Serial.available() > 0)
   {
      i=Serial.read();
      i=map(i, 0, 100, 0, 179);
      servoT1.write(i);
    }
}
```

Here is the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace arduino_throttle
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort uno1 = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            uno1.Open();
            uno1.Write(HScroll.ToString());
            uno1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set the servo angle by scrolling the `hScrollBar` in the program.

Comment: What is HScroll in the C# code? You are writing a string to a comm port then blindly reading the input in the Arduino. My guess is HScroll.ToString() is sending rubbish as far as the Arduino is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

the serial.read () method return the first byte of incoming serial data available
http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read
but you are sending string (array of chars)
try sending from the C# only one byte or char
to do this you need to check the max value is 256

and another thing 
you need to send the value of the scrollbar
(you are sending the entire object in a string)

try this

uno1.Write(Convert.ToByte(HScroll.value));

Comment: now i'm getting this errors

1. cannot convert from 'byte' to 'string'

2. The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: you don't need to send string. just set the servo value in Byte.
that's means that instead of sending "150" you need to send 
Byte b =150;